# What does . ./build.man mean in this piece of code?

Tags: shell

[build.sh](https://github.com/eclipse/che/blob/master/dockerfiles/build.sh) contains such code in the beginning:

```
. ./build.include
```

I am new to shell and don't know what this means.

I know that `.` stands for current directory.
and in the same directory of `build.sh` there is a file named build.include
But what does it mean if `.` and `./build.include` appears in the same row?

Comment: The first `.` is shorthand for `source`, meaning to " source this file (run the content of it). The `./build.include` is exactly as you say, pointing at the current working directory, and executing the build.include file. See https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called `build.include` in the current directory that will be read in and executed in that point in the script.

In this case, `build.include` contains a bunch of library functions used by `build.sh`.